# Salesforce to Salesforce connection - Update existing record during insertion

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I have salesforce to salesforce connection between two salesforce org(org 1 and org 2 ). But I don't want the record to be inserted in org 2 whenever a new record is inserted in org 1. I want to check for certain criteria in org 2 and with respect to that, I want to insert a new record or update existing record. 
Is this possible?

Comment: How is the records been shared there might be some apex code which creates `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` right?

Comment: Do you want a record that is created in Org1 to only exist in Org2 if it matches some criteria in Org2? If so could you handle this with an After Insert trigger that removes the sharing and deletes the record?